# AJAX POST not working when file is included in another file

Tags: php, ajax

I have three php files that is header.php,search.php and index.php. In header.php I am sending ajax POST request to search.php for live search. header.php is included in index.php file. The ajax code works fine when I run only header.php, but it doesn’t work when index.php is executed. My code is as follows:

header.php :

```
<script>
function showResult(str,str2) {
  if (str.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
    return;
  }
  else
  {   alert("fff");

    var url = 'search.php';
   $.post(url,{str:str,str2:str2},function(data){

    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #DDD";
document.getElementById("livesearch").style.backgroundColor="#A5ACB2";
document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=data;
   });
  }

}
</script>

********************************************************************88
```

search.php :

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("buynsell");
$text=$_POST["str"];
$category=$_POST["str2"];
 $results='';

$query=("SELECT title from productdesc where title LIKE '$text%' AND category_name='".$category."' ");

    $result = mysql_query($query);
     while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $results.=$row->title."<br>"; 
     }
    echo $results;
?>

**********************************************8
```

index.php :

Here I am including header.php

```
<body>
<div class="container" style="font-size:14px">

<?php include '../common/header.php'; ?>
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: showing no error..control goes to else statement in header.php because alert message is displayed..but if I put alert msg after post statement it is not showed

Comment: Can you check the error log of your server?

Comment: got it...search.php and index.php should be in the same folder..thanks

Comment: I have added this as an answer to help future users having similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

As things turned out, the problem was that `search.php` and `index.php` were assumed to be in the same folder, yet they were in different folders. A glance into the server error logs immediately lead the op to the solution, who with this simple step was able to solve the problem without the need for any additional help.